# Convert dwg to obj with Java without 3rd party application

Tags: java, dwg

Is there a way to convert AutoCAD file DWG to OBJ by code with Java? Without using a third party application.

I need to import the DWG file, convert it to OBJ then display it in HTML5 Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it is possible to do this with java, especially without third party libraries. Both DWG and OBJ are binary formats and there is no built in libraries to interpret these formats.

There is only 1 java open source library that I am aware of that can parse a AutoCAD dxf file[(Kabeja)](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/) , but this will mean converting a dwg to a dxf file.

There could be commercial libraries available which probably can do this.

Comment: The problem is complicated, the client wants to click on a "Import AutoCAD File" button then I need it to be converted to OBJ or DAE to be parsed and displayed in the canvas. Kabeja is an application (.exe)
I need the conversion to be done by code, if there's any Java class that can do it, it will be great!